# How to send JSON messages to Kafka using a generic class in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a generic class and I do not know how to produce and consume message in Kafka, JSON format format while using that class.

Here is my `KafkaConsumerConfig`

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

import com.ibil.ocpi22.utils.kafka.dto.TestClass;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, TestClass> consumerFactory() `your text`{
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9094");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TestClass> listener() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TestClass> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

`KafkaProducerConfig`

```java
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

import com.ibil.ocpi22.utils.kafka.dto.TestClass;

@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, TestClass> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9094");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, TestClass> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

`Response` class

```java
import java.time.Instant;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Response<T> {

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private T data;
    
    @JsonProperty("timestamp")
    private Instant timestamp;
    
}
```

`TestClass`

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class TestClass{
    private String token;
    private String url;
}
```

For example, I expect to see below output in the Kafka consumer side.

```json
{
    "data": {
      "token": "special_token_text",
      "url": "SpecialUrl"
    }
    "timestamp": "2023-05-05T09:52:01Z)"
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect to see the raw JSON? You have configured the consumer to deserialize it back to a `TestClass` with `JsonDeserializer`.

Comment: @GaryRussell Because this is requirement and it doesn't work. That's the problem. For example, sometimes TestClass can contain another custom class. In this case I have exception like this "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't serialize data [com.ibil.ocpi22.response.Response@780a12c1] for topic [TEST]:org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer:serialize:216"

Comment: Then you should use a `StringDeserializer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the raw JSON, use a `StringDeserializer` instead of the `JsonDeserializer`, e.g.

```java
@KafkaListener
void listen(String json) {
    ...
}
```

But that won't solve your

> Can't serialize data [com.ibil.ocpi22.response.Response@780a12c1] for topic [TEST]:org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer:serialize:216"

That is an entirely different problem on the producer side; you would need to provide much more information about that - probably should be in a new question.